# Read-only file system - LXC

Tags: linux, containers, lxc

I'm trying to demonstrate an ROP attack and keep getting a "Read-only file system" error on my LXC container.
I'm trying to execute the command:

```
echo "0" > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

The following is returned:

```
bash: /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space: Read-only file system
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still relevant, you can't change such settings in a Container. Docker doesn't allow this.

> Docker does not support changing sysctls inside of a Container that also modify the host system.

Therefore you have to change the settings "outside" of your Container, on your **host system**.
Just run the same commands on your host system and then create your Container.
 The File **randomize_va_space** in your Container should automatically have your given value **0** in it!